# How to view man pages in a web browser?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, macos

Which .conf file do I need to edit in order to view `man` pages in a web browser? I'd like to use Google Chrome to do this.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this is to put the following command in `~/.profile`:

```
export PAGER="col -b  | open -a /Applications/Safari.app -f"
```

The `PAGER` environmental variable controls what program `man` uses to display man pages. the `col` command removes all of the backspace-formatting from the man page. The `open` command saves the output as a temporary text file and opens it with `Safari.app`.

Or you can edit the PAGER variable in `/private/etc/man.conf`. You could also probably edit the `NROFF` variable and eliminate the need to use `col -b`. See the man page for `man.conf`.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. That does the trick perfectly. I've just altered the line to read: `export PAGER="col -b  | open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app -f"` so it'll open in Chrome instead of Safari.

Comment: I'd been wanting to do this for myself anyway, and I'm glad I finally found time to look into it. I used TextWrangler with the command `/usr/bin/edit --view-top --clean -t "Man page"`

Answer (score 6):

You can add a function to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
function gman () {
     man "$1" | col -b > "/tmp/$1"
     open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" "/tmp/$1"
}
```

Comment: This function wasn't working for me Graham. Not sure why.

Comment: Is Google Chrome in `/Applications/` or somewhere else?

Comment: It's in `/Applications/`.

Comment: Just an additional step. After adding the function in profile folder. Make sure to source it or reopen terminal. [link](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Source_command)
`source ~/.profile`

Comment: In Safari I had to add an extension like `/tmp/$1.txt`.

Answer (score 6):

http://www.bruji.com/bwana/ is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Cheers. That does look interesting, esp. "We just threw in some color, some bold headers and cleaned it up a bit, so they go easy on the eye." I wonder if I can get such functionality from further editing a .conf file?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the solution by graham, but opening the HTML version in the browser:

```
function htman {
    groff -Thtml -mandoc -c $(man --path $1) > /tmp/$1.html
    open /tmp/$1.html
}
```

(Use `>!` instead of `>` for zsh to allow overwriting of the file.)

Comment: I have not seen zsh fail to overwrite pre-existing files when I forget to type `>>` instead of `>`

Comment: Can‘t you pipe this directly into `open -f`?

Comment: No that makes the browser open the source as a text file, unfortunately.

Comment: @WGroleau happened to me when I was writing that.